Escaped backslash (double backslash) in C counting as two bytes in string
I'm a relatively inexperienced programmer and I'm running into some confusion about escaped backslashes. I'm using strings containing literal backslashes to represent Windows filepaths (for some reason forward slashes weren't working even though Windows supports them) and the double backslashes are being accepted by windows, but for some reason, unlike other escaped characters, the double backslashes are being counted by strlen() as two characters instead of one, and I have to malloc() an extra byte for the escape character to prevent a seg fault. Other escapes like '\n' seem to work perfectly normally and count as a single char. Why are my double backslashes "foo\\bar" counting as two chars instead of one?
I'm using VSCodium to write my code, and compiling with MinGW64 GCC in MSYS2.
Code sample: strlen("documents\\notes") returns 16 instead of 15, and takes up 17 bytes including the null terminator.
full code:
https://github.com/WyntrHeart/note/blob/main/note.c
EDIT: To clarify the solution, I thought that my escape backslashes were taking up an extra byte because adding an extra byte to my malloc() calls made the seg fault crashes appear to go away, but I had actually forgotten to allocate memory at all for part of my strings, so it was only ever "working" by luck.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre], and how you count the size of the strings.

strlen("foo\\bar") is 7.  Why do you think it's counting the escaped backslash as 2 characters?  Show the code you are using which causes you to believe it is counted twice; there is probably some trivial error.

Questions needs to be self-contained. Don't post links to code. Such links might disappear, of the contents might change. And also, when you attempt to create a [mre] there's always a chance that you figure out the problem yourself.

By the way, Windows (and MS-DOS before it) have been able to use the forward slash / for over 30 years.

So I've heard but the code simply did not work on Windows until I switched to backslashes. The best I can guess is it didn't like me mixing forward slashes from my code with the environment variables I'm reading that contain backslash paths.

Oh, and never do anything like retVal=(retVal & (!!((!!((str[i]|32u)>='a')) && (!!((str[i]|32u)<='z')))));! In the loop use e.g. if (!isalpha(str[i])) { return 0; }. After the loop just return 1;. Simple, easy to read and understand and maintain, handle both upper and lower case. And also portable to systems which doesn't use ASCII.

There are also other things that could be made much simpler in that code. Like for example the sorting. Or all those global variables (which are a very bad habit).

I didn't want to add a whole extra #include for one function that I can write myself in a single line, although I wasn't aware that there was any such thing as systems that don't use ASCII so I might change that.

Idk if we're supposed to have this conversation in the comments here but could you elaborate on the issue with my sorting? There's a lot that I wanna rework in this hastily made learn-as-I-go code, but the sorting seems to work just fine so I'm curious what I'm doing wrong?

First I would focus on getting your code to work. At that point https://codereview.stackexchange.com is a better venue for critiquing working code.

It does work right now

@WyntrHeart I didn't want to add a whole extra #include for one function that I can write myself in a single line,  Really, really, really bad idea.  Every single line of code you write is a bug waiting to happen, and it doesn't get tested anywhere nearly as much as standard functions do.  And if you bring obscure, dense, impossible-to-understand code like retVal=(retVal & (!!((!!((str[i]|32u)>='a')) && (!!((str[i]|32u)<='z'))))); to any professional code review you'll get summarily tossed out.  If you can't see what code does in about five seconds, it's BAD code.

@AndrewHenle that makes a lot of sense and as a self-teaching novice I appreciate the professional advice a lot, thank you. It was a pretty messy line, especially with so many nested parentheses, so if I can't rewrite it into something readable I'll scrap it and use std isAlpha()

The problem is likely this (from the fullPathOfFileName function):
fullPath = malloc((strlen(notesDirName)+strlen(fileName)+3)*sizeof(char));

You copy notesDirName into fullPath, which is fine.
Then you append a slash (backward or forward) which is fine.
Then you append fileName, which is also fine.
Then comes the problem: You append ".txt" to the string.
In total you add strlen(notesDirName) + 1 + strlen(fileName) + 4 + 1 characters to the string. Which will write out of bounds and give you undefined behavior.
Moral of the story is to not be cheap. Unless you're targeting a system known to have limited memory (small embedded systems), there's plenty of memory around. Heck, even on my old 512 KiB Amiga, memory was usually plenty to allow you some failure margins.

Any time you encounter a "it works on some machines/compilers and not others" situation the "works" is more likely the fluke than the "doesn't work."

Ah! I forgot to add the bytes for the file extension. Idk how the code was working at all like that...

Within the infinite realm of "undefined behavior" possibilities lies "works as expected." In a case like this, it likely means that the memory after the overflowed buffer happens by chance to be zero, allowing it to still be a null-terminated string.

The string does have the right length. Consider the following code.
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", (int)strlen("foo\\bar"));
}

If we compile and run that code, we get 7 in the console. Why, then, does the string appear to be of length 8? It's because it's null-terminated. Whenever you write "foo", that's actually syntactic sugar for { 'f', 'o', 'o', 0 }. The reason it adds a zero is because, whenever a function needs to do operations on the string, it doesn't store the length of the string. Instead, you determine the length at runtime by finding the 0.
To prove this theory, use whatever method of length checking you used on this string: "foo\\\\ar". If you try this string, it'll return a length of 8 as well.
It's likely you're using sizeof, so you can try that as follows.
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof("foo\\\\ar"));
}


To clarify, I'm saying that sizeof(str) includes the 0, whereas strlen doesn't. sizeof is general and works for all arrays, but strlen is specialized on the quirks of strings. You should try, in general, to use functions like the latter--since Cs weak type system leads to lots of errors like this unless you ensure that you're calling the right function.

Its not a null byte issue, I do understand the difference. strlen("documents/notes") was 15 chars as expected, while changing to strlen("documents\\notes") has increased it to 16 chars and I'm having to malloc() an additional byte (17 bytes instead of 16)

@WyntrHeart your second string returns 15 not 16.

Could this be some kind of issue with my MSYS2 and/or MinGW setup? Because testing on my Android phone does give the correct length, while on my Windows PC the escape backslash is counting as an additional char

A quick perusal of the linked code (which should have been a minimal, reproducible example inlined as formatted text) suggests that using sizeof rather than strlen is not the issue. This answer doesn't seem to rise much above a guess without that MRE from the OP.

@Chris My code is reproducable. Copy either snipped into your text editor and build it, and it will compile and behave like I said. Moreover, it was inlined as formatted text. When I made my post, the OP hadn't provided a code snippet yet.
